# Is it possible to recover a task in TFS that's had the status set to Removed?

Tags: tfs

If someone accidentally set the status of a task to "Removed" in TFS 2010, is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>If you just changed the `Status/State` to **Removed** you should be able to create a new Query and search for Removed work items.</strike>

> Go to My Queries, right click -> New Query, adjust the last item to State = Removed and click Run

From the query results you can open up the task and change the Status/State to the appropriate Status/State

*this  assumes that your work item type definition allows for the state to go back to something other than removed*

**Edit**

If you want to alter the behavior for a `Task` in the default scrum template you must modify the `Task.xml` located under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0\Process Template\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions
```

Open the file and add in an additional `<TRANSITION/>` element located under `<TRANSITIONS/>`

```
<TRANSITION from="Removed" to="To Do">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Added back into the backlog" />
  </REASONS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Save the file and update the modified Task work item type definition using [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).  This will overwrite the Scrum Task type and introduce the newly transition from **Removed** to **To Do**

From there you simply need to run a query to find your **Removed** task and change the State.

Comment: I can find the removed items, but there's no way to change the status.   We're using the Scrum process template.

Comment: @chris so you can modify other fields but not the State?  We use the Scrum template as well and I have the option to change the State back to New.

Comment: If I remove a product backlog item, I can change it back to new.  If I remove a task, however, there is no option to change it to anything else.

Comment: @chris missed the note about the task type, see the update you can achieve this by changing the default WIT definition to add a new transition.

Comment: In TFS11 we have modified the Task work item to have the Removed -> To do transition by default.

Comment: @Mark - I don't seem to be able to upload it (VS2010 Tools -> Process Editor, Work Item types, import WIT) and when I open the Task from the server I cannot modify it.  Is there any way to make the change directly on the server?

Comment: @Chris you wont be able to modify it via Open WIT from server you need to modify the xml file from the location given or save the WIT to your machine.  You might need elevated TFS permissions to upload the WIT however.

Comment: Got it to work:  I ended up exporting the task, edited that Task.xml file, and then imported that.  For some reason, importing the edited Task.xml file in the original location you mentioned did not work, even though there were no errors during the import.

Answer (score 2):

You can also duplicate the work item to create a complete copy of this item in the To Do state. This is a bit of a work around, but is simpler and quicker to do. You can do this by:

- Open the work item.
- Click Tools on the menu.
- Choose "Create Copy of Work Item"