# Accidentally changed Task state to 'Removed', want to undo

Tags: tfs

I accidentally changed a few tasks from 'In Progress' to 'Removed'.  The tasks were saved, I can see no way to undo this change.  Is there a way, or do I just need to re-create the tasks?

Comment: What process definition are you using (selecting when the TFS project was created)? If customised you would need to look at the work item definition (editor or the XML) to look at the available state transitions.

Comment: If you use the TFS 2010 Scrum template, then see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106962/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-task-in-tfs-thats-had-the-status-set-to-removed)

Comment: That's actually my workmate.  We got it working... thanks

Comment: @Geoff, it would be helpful if you shared the solution.

Comment: This problem was answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106962/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-task-in-tfs-thats-had-the-status-set-to-removed

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new query and choose state "Removed" and you will find it

[image]